Zed Editor for Mobile Development (React Native and Swift)
I'm new to react native and I was wondering if anyone uses it for mobile dev? I'm currently using Zed IDE and its been absolutely incredible for web dev. However Mobile Dev requires a screen where you can see the changes being made in the UI in realtime. I've searched everywhere but I cant find a solution to this.
If yes, how do you get preview screens working?
I tried searching everywhere and I cant seem to find the solution to this

Not sure exactly what you're asking but if you're asking how to get a preview of your app as your developing; most React Native developers use Expo. You can run it on an emulator or you can download the Expo Go app on your mobile device and check your prototype there.
Here is the documentation of getting started with Expo.
https://reactnative.dev/docs/environment-setup?guide=quickstart
To create an Expo project first run:

npm install -g expo-cli

Then in your project root directory run:

npx create-expo-app AwesomeProject


I'm running a code editor and I basically want to be able to preview apps/run an emulator like the Expo Go as I'm creating my app if that makes sense.
I've just been doing it the manual way by going through terminal specific ways of accessing the built in emulators by google and apple if that makes sense
